# How to commaize the data values provided to a chart in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I've got this code to add data to a chart:

```
datasets: [
    {
        data: [2755, 2256, 1637, 1608, 1603, 1433, 1207, 1076, 1056, 1048],
        . . .
```

I want it to be commaized, so that "2755" appears as "2,755" etc. So I tried this::

```
datasets: [
    {
        data: [addCommas(2755), addCommas(2256), addCommas(1637), addCommas(1608), addCommas(1603), addCommas(1433), addCommas(1207), addCommas(1076), addCommas(1056), addCommas(1048)],
        . . .

function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

...but that almost completely obliterates my pie; the pie itself is invisible, although the legend I've added is visible albeit mangled.

This fails with the same exact effect:

```
data: ["2,755", "2,256", "1,637", "1,608", "1,603", "1,433", "1,207", "1,076", "1,056", "1,048"],
```

Since the data is embedded within a canvas, I don't think I can apply some easy universal solution, but if there is, that'd be great; otherwise, what is a way to accomplish this commaification of numeric values?

### UPDATE

I want to try felipeptcho's answer, but I don't know where exactly to put that code within what I've got, which is this:

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Bananas (18%)",
        "Lettuce, Romaine (14%)",
        "Melons, Watermelon (10%)",
        "Pineapple (10%)",
        "Berries (10%)",
        "Lettuce, Spring Mix (9%)",
        "Broccoli (8%)",
        "Melons, Honeydew (7%)",
        "Grapes (7%)",
        "Melons, Cantaloupe (7%)"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [2755, 2256, 1637, 1608, 1603, 1433, 1207, 1076, 1056, 1048],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FFE135",
                "#3B5323",
                "#fc6c85",
                "#ffec89",
                "#021c3d",
                "#3B5323",
                "#046b00",
                "#cef45a",
                "#421C52",
                "#FEA620"
            ]
        }]
};

var optionsPie = {
    responsive: true,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true
}

var ctx = $("#top10ItemsChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var top10PieChart = new Chart(ctx,
{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: optionsPie
});

$("#top10Legend").html(top10PieChart.generateLegend());
```

### UPDATE 2

It is still not working; here's what it looks like after adding that code:

[image]

This is what it looks like without the new code, hovering over bananas (showing "2755" which I would like to be "2,755"):

[image]

Simply commenting out this:

```
data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(formatter.format);
});
```

...returns it to its previous appearance, but I still don't have the values commaized, of course.

This is my code which breaks the pie (when the code above is *not* commented out):

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Bananas (18%)",
        "Lettuce, Romaine (14%)",
        "Melons, Watermelon (10%)",
        "Pineapple (10%)",
        "Berries (10%)",
        "Lettuce, Spring Mix (9%)",
        "Broccoli (8%)",
        "Melons, Honeydew (7%)",
        "Grapes (7%)",
        "Melons, Cantaloupe (7%)"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [2755, 2256, 1637, 1608, 1603, 1433, 1207, 1076, 1056, 1048],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FFE135",
                "#3B5323",
                "#fc6c85",
                "#ffec89",
                "#021c3d",
                "#3B5323",
                "#046b00",
                "#cef45a",
                "#421C52",
                "#FEA620"
            ]
        }
    ]
};
data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(formatter.format);
});

var optionsPie = {
    responsive: true,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true
}

var ctx = $("#top10ItemsChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var top10PieChart = new Chart(ctx,
{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: optionsPie
});

$("#top10Legend").html(top10PieChart.generateLegend());
```

### UPDATE 3

Wait a minute - I updated that last screenshot above without really paying attention to its appearance, and it has already been fixed. All it took was adding this line, as mentioned felipeptcho:

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
```

Without it, the values contain no commas; with it, they do - nothing else required!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat();
var data = {labels: ["..."], datasets: [{data: [2755, 2256, 1637, 1608, 1603, 1433, 1207, 1076, 1056, 1048], backgroundColor: ["..."]}]};

data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(formatter.format);
});

// Output: {"labels":["..."],"datasets":[{"data":["2,755","2,256","1,637","1,608","1,603","1,433","1,207","1,076","1,056","1,048"],"backgroundColor":["..."]}]}
console.log(data);
```

Another way of doing it is implementing a label callback:

```
...

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat();

var optionsPie = {
    responsive: true,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ": " +
                    formatter.format(data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index]);
            }
        }
    }
};

...

var top10PieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: optionsPie
});

...
```

Comment: I want to try this; please see my Update.

Comment: It still doesn't work; maybe it's an issue with the legend - the legend doesn't get along with the new code, and then impacts the pie as well. See Update 2.

Comment: Oh. Now I have understood what you want. You should not change the data array. You have to implement a custom tooltip function. I'll implement a full working example. Just a moment.

Comment: Please see Update 3 and/or my auto-answer.

Comment: I saw, but I can't reproduce it. I could make it work using a tooltip callback function. I'll update my answer so you can check.

Comment: See my updated auto-answer; there was another piece of code needed.

Comment: I've copied all your code, but it doesn't work as you're saying. See: https://jsfiddle.net/96epw5jg/ Now, I've found the "right" way of doing it, using a tooltip callback. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/p47a2kgc/

Comment: Works for me - why don't you add it to your answer here (if you haven't already), and I'll bountify it ASAP.

Comment: Man, I could make it work! The reason it was not working was that my default locale is pt-BR. The thousands separator here is a dot (`.`) not a comma (`,`). I think that, at some point, Chart.js tries to convert the formatted data strings to numbers using the browser default locale. As I was using en-US in the source code, Chart.js was not being able to make the conversion. That's it. ;)

Comment: I improved my answer and removed the `"en-US"` parameter, so the number formatting will always use the default locale for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
datasets: [
{
    labels: [addCommas(2755), addCommas(2256), addCommas(1637), addCommas(1608)],
    data: [2755, 2256, 1637, 1608],
    . . .
```

Comment: I need different labels, such as: 
labels: [
                    "APPLES, GALA WAXF 138", . . .

Answer (score 1):

All that is really needed is the first line of felipeptcho's code, namely:

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
```

...and then somewhere after that this:

```
data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(formatter.format);
});
```

Even when I had that last code after a block of other code declaring datasets and data for a different chart, it worked on the chart/data under discussion.

That's all! It simply works. How, I don't quite grok, but it does, so I'm satisfied.